# Sage: Polynomial ring over finite field - inverting a polynomial non-prime

Tags: field, sage, polynomials, ring, inverse

I'm trying to recreate the wiki's example procedure, available here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRUEncrypt

I've run into an issue while attempting to invert the polynomials.

The SAGE code below seems to be working fine for the given *p=3*, which is a prime number.

However, the representation of the polynomial in the field generated by *q*=32 ends up wrong, because it behaves as if the modulus was *2*.

Here's the code in play:

```
F = PolynomialRing(GF(32),'a')
a = F.gen()
Ring = F.quotient(a^11 - 1, 'x')
x = Ring.gen()
pollist = [-1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1]

fq = Ring(pollist)
print(fq)
print(fq^(-1))
```

The Ring is described as follows:

```
Univariate Quotient Polynomial Ring in x over Finite Field in z5 of size 2^5 with modulus a^11 + 1
```

And the result:

```
x^10 + x^9 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1
x^5 + x + 1
```

I've tried to replace the Finite Field with IntegerModRing(32), but the inversion ends up demanding a field, as implied by the message:

```
NotImplementedError: The base ring (=Ring of integers modulo 32) is not a field
```

Any suggestions as to how I could obtain the correct inverse of f (mod q) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`GF(32)` is the finite field with 32 elements, not the integers modulo 32. You must use `Zmod(32)` (or `IntegerModRing(32)`, as you suggested) instead.

As you point out, Sage psychotically bans you from computing inverses in ℤ/32ℤ[a]/(a¹¹-1) because that is not a field, and not even a factorial ring. It can, however, compute those inverses when they exist, only you must ask more kindly:

```
sage: F.<a> = Zmod(32)[]
sage: fq = F([-1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1])
sage: print(fq)
31*a^10 + a^9 + a^6 + 31*a^4 + a^2 + a + 31
sage: print(fq.inverse_mod(a^11 - 1))
16*a^8 + 4*a^7 + 10*a^5 + 28*a^4 + 9*a^3 + 13*a^2 + 21*a + 1
```

Not ideal, admittedly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `Zmod(32)` seems to be a synonym to `IntegerModRing(32)`, which I've described above.

Apparently using these two makes it impossible to calculate the inverse using `^(-1)`, because the program demands a field.

I've made some attempts to use `xgcd`, but to no avail.

Could you please share with me an inverting technique using the `Zmod(32)` you provided?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read your question entirely. I updated the answer.

Comment: Except, this gives wrong results, and it seems to be a Sage bug).